# Does killing in the opening sequence count against the Pacifist achievement?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

In Deus Ex: Human Revolution, is it possible to get the pacifist achievement even if one kills enemies in the opening sequence?  Boss fight kills do not count against the achievement, so I'm wondering if the same applies to the start of the game since you have fewer tools at your disposal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>According to [this thread](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=325602) at Xbox360Achievements.org, kills in the opening sequence do count towards the achievement.</strike>

Since my original link died, the [IGN Strategize](http://www.ign.com/videos/2011/08/25/ign-strategize-deus-ex-human-revolution) on Deus Ex: Human Revolution also states that kills during the opening (pre-augmentation) sequence do count against the Pacifist achievement.

Comment: Your link died - it comes back with a "no thread specified".

Comment: @Raven Sadly it appears that the thread was deleted. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can't kill, but you *can* shoot the yellow gas-canisters in the vicinity of enemies, that will render them unconscious.