# Are the gas cylinders the same as gas grenades in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm doing a new run in *Deus Ex: Human Revolution* (going for Pacifist and Foxiest of the Hounds) and I was wondering if the gas cylinders you find lying around count as the knock out gas found in the gas grenades or if it is lethal.

I'm in the opening sequence and using the cylinders seems to be the best way to deal with the mercenaries.

Comment: Afaik you can kill the guards in the opening sequence and still get pacifism.

Comment: @Holger: That is a somewhat controversial claim. I think if I were going for pacifism, I'd probably just save and reload a lot until I got by without killing them rather than take the chance on ruining a pacifistic playthrough without knowing it.

Comment: @Jprete: Yeah I just thought I read it somewhere on this site...
but looking at the wiki it doesn't seem to be true, though it might be a bug:
http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Pacifist

Comment: Another thing that points towards it count towards pacifist:
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28617/does-killing-in-the-opening-sequence-count-against-the-pacifist-achievement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gas in them is non-lethal, so yes, enemies will be knocked out by the gas. But, if you actually throw or drop it on them, they will die.

Comment: Thanks. I never bothered checking in my first playthrough.